# How to use the Like statement in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I m facing a problem that my query can execute but when i call the stored procedure meet operand should contain 1 columns. The above is some part of my query

```
if p_Opt = 'RETRIEVE-P' THEN    

Set @'query' = ('SELECT Company,Branch,user_id,name,priority,email,UserGroup, Status FROM UserAuth WHERE 1=1 ');

    If p_Company Is Not Null  THEN

            Set @'query' = @'query' + ' AND Company LIKE '''+ '%' +  p_Company + '%' + '''';
        END if;
```

END IF;

What is the problem??Is it correct for my query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using single qoutes use double quotes in like query something like below.

```
 if p_Opt = 'RETRIEVE-P' THEN    

    Set @'query' = ('SELECT Company,Branch,user_id,name,priority,email,UserGroup, Status FROM UserAuth WHERE 1=1 ');

        If p_Company Is Not Null  THEN

                Set @'query' = @'query' + ' AND Company LIKE "%' +  p_Company + '%"';
            END if;
```

Comment: Actually, this works but is wrong, because it is vulnerable to SQL injection.  MySQL provides the `QUOTE()` function to properly quote literals if you insist on concatenation, and it understands how to handle NULL.  Prepared statements would be even better. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_quote